# Python logger DEBUG is not shown

Tags: python, logging

Given this setup, I cannot see any `debug` logs:

```
import logging
import coloredlogs

coloredlogs.install(isatty=True)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Show the current debug level
logger.critical(logger.level)


logger.critical("critical")
logger.error("error")
logger.warning("warning")
logger.info("info")
logger.debug("debug") <-- NOT SHOWN!
```

Yet if I change to
`coloredlogs.install(level=logging.DEBUG,isatty=True)`

I get all the `DEBUG` notices but they include other libs debug messages (botocore, urllib..) which is unwanted since I want to see only my debug notices.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

instead of `logger.setLevel`? I assume you only set the level of that logger, but the corresponding handlers still have a higher level, so the message is [ignored](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

Comment: Not working, but
'coloredlogs.install(level=logging.DEBUG,isatty=True)'
Does the job, but it shows a lot more debugging, even for external libs which is unwanted.